# How to get the MS Word Form Fields Check box associated text and their value using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-automation

How to get the MS word document checkbox form element associated text value. I am able to extract the value of the checkbox. I tried with bookmark and name properties and found that there is no value associated with bookmark filed of the checkbox. I got the following output. Any thoughts?

**Form Fields:**

[image: form]

**Code:**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strCheckBoxName As String
    Dim strCheckBoxValue As String
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.FormFields.Count
        If ActiveDocument.FormFields(i).CheckBox Then
            strCheckBoxName = ActiveDocument.FormFields(i).Name
            strCheckBoxValue = ActiveDocument.FormFields(i).CheckBox.Value
            Debug.Print strCheckBoxName & " = " & strCheckBoxValue
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
Check1 = True
Check1 = True
Check1 = True
Check1 = False
Check1 = False
Check1 = False
```

**Solution looking for:**

```
A = True
B = True
C = True
D = False
E = False
F = False
```

Comment: It may be that you should use strCheckBoxName = ActiveDocument.FormFields(i).CheckBox.Name, since the field name is the same for all.

Comment: I tried it. But no luck. It is throwing null.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

By default, when a FormField Check Box is added, it has a Bookmark (name) of `Check#` where # is sequential starting at `1` until `n`. Copy and Paste are your friends with FormFields, so one of two things will occur if you go that route to get, say your 1000 FormFields:

- 1: If you do not alter the value of Bookmark (e.g. default to `Check1`) and copy and paste that say 1000 times, you end up with 1000 FormFields of Bookmark Check1.
- 2: If you alter the value of Bookmark (e.g. to `A`) and copy and past that say 1000 times, only the first FormField retains the Bookmark of `A` while the rest have a Bookmark that is empty.

You can alter the Check Box default bookmark value (in this case Check1 as a result from copy and paste over and over) to a sequential value such as A1, A2, A3, A4 or Check1, Check2, Check3, etc... by using the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strCheckBoxName As String
    Dim strCheckBoxValue As String
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.formFields.Count
        If ActiveDocument.formFields(i).CheckBox Then
            strCheckBoxName = ActiveDocument.formFields(i).Name
            strCheckBoxValue = ActiveDocument.formFields(i).CheckBox.Value
            Debug.Print strCheckBoxName & " = " & strCheckBoxValue
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub RenameCheckBox()
    Dim oFields As formFields
    Dim oVar As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long

    x = 0
    i = 0

    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect
    End If
    Set oFields = ActiveDocument.formFields
    For x = 1 To oFields.Count
        oFields(x).Select
        Select Case oFields(x).Type
            Case wdFieldFormCheckBox
                oVar = oFields(x).CheckBox.Value
                i = i + 1
                With Dialogs(wdDialogFormFieldOptions)
                    .Name = "Check" & i
                    .Execute
                End With
                oFields(x).CheckBox.Value = oVar
            Case Else
                'Do Nothing
        End Select
    Next x
    ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True

    Call Test

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the document is protected with values and also the document are more then 1000.

Comment: If there are more than 1000 of these check box form fields, what is their naming convention?

Comment: "I tried with bookmark and name properties and found that there is no value associated with bookmark filed of the checkbox." How did you check the bookmark property? Use of VBA or did you unprotect the document?