# Determine if checkbox in word document is checked or not - char u0015, microsoft.office.interop.word in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, char, office-interop, cpu-word

## Prerequired information

having a word document with the following cell:
[image]

accessing the cells text like this using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word:

```
Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);
Table docTable = doc.Tables[1];
string field = table.Rows[12].Cells[2].Range.Text
```

text result is:

> \u0015 will be taken over from employee (wird übernommen von MA)
> \u0015 needs to be ordered (muss neu bestellt werden)
> \u0015 no need for Laptop/PC (braucht kein Laptop/PC)

## Issue

`\u0015` is the small checkbox in the word file. But no matter, if the checkbox is checked or not, the char representation is `\u0015`.

## Question

is there any way to determine if the little checkbox from `\u0015 no need for Laptop/PC (braucht kein Laptop/PC)` is checked or not?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802586/how-to-get-the-ms-word-form-fields-check-box-associated-text-and-their-value-usi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FormFields` property of the Document class to access the controls. Then you can use the [CheckBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.formfield.checkbox) property which returns a `CheckBox` object that represents a check box form field.

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = False
```